# Remove "title" row above header in shiny datatable excel output?

Tags: r, excel, shiny, datatables, dt

In my shiny app, I'm using:

```
# server.R
  output$out_table = DT::renderDataTable(
    func_to_creat_dataframe(),
    rownames= FALSE,
    extensions = c('Buttons'),
    options = list(
      pageLength = 96,
      lengthMenu = c(96, 384, 1536),
      dom = 'Blfrtip',
      buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
    )
  )
```

```
# UI.R
DT::dataTableOutput('out_table')
```

...and when I use the "Excel" button to export the table, the exported table has a "title" row directly above the header row. This title row consists of one merged cell that spans across the entire header. How do I remove this? This title row interferes with downstream processing of the file, and it's completely unnecessary, so I don't see why it appears to be default for the datatable file export buttons.

Answer (score 4):

Try that:

```
DT::datatable(
  iris,
  rownames= FALSE,
  extensions = c('Buttons'),
  options = list(
    pageLength = 96,
    lengthMenu = c(96, 384, 1536),
    dom = 'Blfrtip',
    buttons = list(
      'copy', 
      'csv', 
      list(extend = 'excel', title = NULL), 
      'pdf', 
      'print'
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It works except, at least for Mac 2011 Excel, I get an error/warning stating: `Excel could not open the document because some of the content is unreadable. Do you want to open and repair this workbook?` Clicking `Open and repair` works. The excel repair log file shows: `</summary><repairedParts summary="Following is a list of repairs:"><repairedPart xml:space="preserve">Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part. </repairedPart></repairedParts></recoveryLog>`

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 2013 Excel either. I get the same issue as above

Comment: @Kevin And this works when there is a title? Strange;

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, didn't try. I just don't have title as an input at all. Adding title = NULL creates an unrepairable workbook though

Comment: @Kevin This bug has been encountered [in the past](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/127172/#Comment_127172). DT uses the buttons extension version 1.5.2, it is strange that this bug still occurs.